# java - Jar file can't be executed on another pc

Tags: java

I have an executable jar file I compiled from my program and I ran it on my PC. It works perfectly fine when I ran it in my command prompt using `java -jar [nameofjar.jar]`

However, I tried testing it on another pc. Using command prompt to run the same jar file, it throws an error:

```
D:\QA06122018_2>java -jar Indexing.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at IndexDriver.processText(IndexDriver.java:81)
        at IndexDriver.index(IndexDriver.java:140)
        at Main.main(Main.java:44).....
```

Both PC are using the same operating system and settings.
I even looked at the code regarding the error and there doesn't seem to be any problem with it. Ran fine on my IDE.

Is there anything I might overlooked?

EDIT:

The code :

```
 public PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

     MysqlAccessIndex con = new MysqlAccessIndex();
        public Connection con1 = con.connect();
        String path1;


        public void index() throws Exception {
               // Connection con1 = con.connect();
                try {


                    Statement statement = con1.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active' LIMIT 5");


                    while (rs.next()) {
                        // get the filepath of the PDF document
                         path1 = rs.getString(2);
                       int getNum = rs.getInt(1);

                        Statement test = con1.createStatement();
                        test.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where UniqueID="+getNum);



                        try {
                            // call the index function




                            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path1),MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

                            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

                                for(int p=1; p<=document.getNumberOfPages();++p) {
                                    tStripper.setStartPage(p);
                                    tStripper.setEndPage(p);
                                    try {
                                        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                                        processText(pdfFileInText);
                                        System.out.println("Page  "+p+" done");
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Statement statement1 = con1.createStatement();
                                        statement1.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET Error ='E0003' where UniqueID="+getNum);
                                        statement1.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET Status ='Error' where UniqueID="+getNum);
                                      con1.commit();
                                      con1.close();
                                    }
                                }


                                }







                            // After completing the process, update status: Complete
                            Statement pre= con1.createStatement();
                            pre.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Complete' where UniqueID="+getNum);

                           // con1.commit();

                            preparedStatement.close();



                           document.close();

                            System.out.println("Successfully commited changes to the database!");
                            con1.commit();
                           // con1.close();
                           // updateComplete_DB(getNum);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            try {
                                System.err.println(e);


                                Statement statement1 = con1.createStatement();
                                statement1.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Error' where UniqueID="+getNum);
                                statement1.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET Error ='E0002' where UniqueID="+getNum);

                                con1.commit();
                                // add rollback function
                                rollbackEntries();


                            }catch (Exception e1){
                                System.out.println("Could not rollback updates :" + e1.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                                 //  con1.close();
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
                   //System.out.println("lalala");

                }
        //con1.commit();
         con1.close();

            }
```

Calling the method:

```
 public void processText(String text) throws SQLException {

    String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");


        String sql="insert IGNORE into  test.indextable values (?,?);";


        preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
        int i=0;
        for (String word : words) {

            // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
            // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
            // insert every word directly to table db
            word=word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, path1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);

              preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

 }





    }
    preparedStatement.close();

}
```

Comment: We can't know what you might have overlooked if we can't see the code that throws the NPE. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Slaw I edited my post. But how would you explain that it runs fine on mine PC and not on the other?

Comment: @Daredevil you still not posting the **complete** code (for example, what `con1` in `processText` is?), it is impossible for others to "explain that it runs fine on mine PC and not on the other". Or the answer SHOULD be "Because you made something error.".

Comment: The NullPointerException stack trace tells you exactly where to start looking: IndexDriver.java line 81. Unfortunately you haven't indicated where line 81 is.

Comment: Line 81 - points at `preparedStatement.close()` inside processText method

Comment: That means that preparedStatement is null at that point in the code execution.

Comment: I would suggest you step through your code with a debugger on both computers to find out why `preparedStatement` is `null` on one and not the other.

Comment: I think i might have figured it out, that particular file is not a readable PDF, hence there was no extraction at all from the file

Comment: See my answer for why that causes an NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that there were no lines to process.

You appear to only create prepared statements inside the `for (String line : lines) {` loop. But you only close the last statement you created (outside that loop).

When you don't have any lines, `preparedStatement` is null, because you never created one.

Even when you have lines to process, you are creating lots of prepared statements but only closing the last one.

You should probably create one prepared statement at the start of the method and reuse it for the whole method, closing it at the end.

Comment: What do you mean create one prepared statement at the start and reuse it?

Comment: A prepared statement can be reused for multiple executions. The '?' placeholders get replaced with the values you want to use for each execution. One of the main benefits (other than eliminating SQL injection) is that it is much faster to prepare one statement and reuse it a lot of times than to execute a large number of regular statements.

Comment: While you are trying to figure all of this out, I would recommend adding debug logging so that you can see during execution what values your variables have and what code paths are being executed. It will help you understand where the bugs are in your code.

Comment: You are already reusing your statement for each word, just move the creation of the statement outside the 'line' loop.

Comment: So from what I understand from your answer, I have to move the initial prepareStatement outside the loop (along with the sql declaration) and then the preparedstatement.close() can be remained the same as it waS?

Comment: Given that I can't compile and test your code, I can only say try it and see what happens.

Comment: I tested it, the error is now gone. Although, it seems that it is processing it page although the file is unreadable so no words actually get processed into the db